# Programmatically change Apple Mail (Mail.app) settings via command line

Tags: mail.app

I'd like to change some settings in Apple Mail via command line/script, to automate computer deployment.

What I currently need to tweak is:

1. compose font, size and color
2. signature
3. disable *General > Follow up suggestions*

Is it all or any of it possible? thanks

Comment: Not sure about 1 and 3 but you can set your signature with `defaults write com.apple.mail Signature "Your signature"`

Comment: thanks. Do you know how can I assign the signature to an account? I have a local iCloud and a Gmail one

Comment: Yes. You can use `defaults write com.apple.mail AccountName Signature "Your signature"`. Just replace `AccountName` by the name of the account for which you want to set the signature